# only one direction in a vertical slider

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uislider

In a application for iPad, I'm trying to build a slider that only moves up, and it will be reseted by a button.

I found out how to put it vertically, just make a transform: `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`.
But how can I block the slider to move down??

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question. All I an say is major overriding.

Comment: @AceLegend No overriding needed at all. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup a handler for the slider's value:

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderUpdated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

You need an instance variable for the current slider value:

```
float _sliderValue;
```

And you need to implement the `sliderUpdated:` method you setup above.

```
- (void)sliderUpdated:(UISlider *)slider {
    float val = slider.value;
    if (val < _sliderValue) {
        // The user tried to move the slider down - move it back up
        slider.value = _sliderValue;
    } else {
        // The user moved the slider up - save this as the new value
        _sliderValue = val;
    }
}
```

Make sure that your "Reset" button handler resets the `_sliderValue` back to the slider's minimum value.

Comment: I thought in this approach.. but the slider will not change his value?? it must not change the value.. I will try it. Thanks

Comment: @Frade With this approach, the slider's value can only go up, not down.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom UISlider subclass and implement the `- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method to check if the slider is being moved down.

Comment: And then... Don't move it I guess. Not sure how well this would work, but it is probably the method you would use. Deciding on what how to disable moving down might be a challenge. I'm not sure about that though.